# Const argument in virtual type breaks magento2

Tags: payment-gateway, virtualtype

So, I'm using the code from here [sample-payment](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) and I have in `di.xml` the following code:

```
<!-- Payment Method Facade configuration -->
<virtualType name="SamplePaymentGatewayFacade" type="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="code" xsi:type="const">Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
        <argument name="formBlockType" xsi:type="string">Magento\Payment\Block\Form</argument>
        <argument name="infoBlockType" xsi:type="string">Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Block\Info</argument>
        <argument name="valueHandlerPool" xsi:type="object">SamplePaymentGatewayValueHandlerPool</argument>
        <argument name="commandPool" xsi:type="object">SamplePaymentGatewayCommandPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- Configuration reader -->
<virtualType name="SamplePaymentGatewayConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="methodCode" xsi:type="const">Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

that when running it in this way it breaks the magento2. Note: the code is under `root/app/code` stored.

With breaks I mean the following:

when I run a simple `php bin/magento list` I receive:

```
root@ea40a2340686:/var/www/magento2# php bin/magento list
Magento CLI version 2.1.10

Usage:
 command [options] [arguments]

Options:
 --help (-h)           Display this help message
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version
 --ansi                Force ANSI output
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question

Available commands:
 help   Displays help for a command
 list   Lists commands
We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code generation directories. By default, they are: var/cache, var/di, var/generation, and var/page_cache.



  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Constant name is expected.
```

And if I try now to do something in the browser I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider, because the name is already in use in /var/www/magento2/app/code/Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/Model/Ui/ConfigProvider.php on line 22

The class:

```
/**
 * Class ConfigProvider
 */
final class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const CODE = 'sample_gateway';

    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'transactionResults' => [
                        ClientMock::SUCCESS => __('Success'),
                        ClientMock::FAILURE => __('Fraud'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

If I remove this line (and the other one in the other virtual type) in the `di.xml`:

```
<argument name="code" xsi:type="const">Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
```

everything works again.

So, **my question**: What is wrong by this declaration of the **const**?

As from the `config.xsd` and `types.xsd` everything should be ok.

```
<!-- config.xsd -->
<xs:complexType name="const">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="argumentType" />
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

and

```
<!-- types.xsd -->
<xs:complexType name="argumentType" abstract="true" mixed="true">
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

PS: I'm using Magento2 V2.1.10 with php 7.0.12 in the magento2devbox.

Comment: was no typo, was just another namespace, but it can appear also if you misstype something (that's why I wrote careful with the typos). I wouldn't remove this question/answer, because for me it took 1-2 days to find the problem and there is no other helpful sources + the gitter/irc is useless no one answers in there - it's like a dead community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently for me was just a type in the namespace of the `ConfigProvider` class. Instead of `namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Model\Ui;` was only `namespace Magento\MyTestPaymentGateway\Model\Ui;`.

I've copied this from another test project and that's the reason didn't find the const.

PS: If you have this error -> be careful with typos!!